# What exactly is a Die ID?

Tags: arm, die

I am an iOS developer from Germany. Apple has deprecated the UDID access for normal AppStore Apps. So I am searching for a replacement, and finaly came over the DieID. I investigated a bit, but I was not able to figure out if this ID is unique. (The UDID is a Unique Device Identefier, it lets the developer to identify the user, beacause the UDID is unique for every device. The UDID is made from SHA1(serial + IMEI + wifiMac + bluetoothMac) or SHA1(serial + ECID + wifiMac + bluetoothMac). All of these parameters has been made unaccessible in iOS 7 and 8.

Does anyone know if the DieID is unique for every die? I already contacted Samsung, but they didn't replyed yet.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is not about electronic design.

Comment: This question is on topic because it is about SW development with focus on electronic design.

Comment: What exactly is this "DieID" and how you can get it?

Comment: The "DieID" is the identification of the die. The die itself if the the pure circuit of the IC, without the plastic housing. Its basically the little squares on a wafer. You can get the DieID with MobileGestalt.h (Only tested on iOS 7 and 8)

Comment: Whenever you start relying on unofficial/undocumented APIs, be prepared to get kicked off App Store. Apple clearly does not want you to identify the user without her consent so you should not do it. Use the approved APIs such as `ASIdentifierManager`.

Comment: This app will never hit the AppStore. ASIdentifierManager is able to give me a unique ID, but it can be changed by the user under Settings.app --> Privacy --> Ad -> Reset Ad-ID. So this is not what I need.

Comment: The technical question **actually asked** belongs on electronics.stackexchange.com

Comment: As far as alternatives, since it is stated that the interest arrises from some sort sort of private/corporate distribution "which will never hit the AppStore", the best solution is probably to make the app only function after registering with a server which will hand out an ID associated with a piece or real-world-unique information such as an employee ID, test pool invitation email, or whatever.  It doesn't matter if this gets cleared, because the only way to make the app functional again would be to re-register it, which would result in being handed the same number as before.

Comment: The unique thing about DieID is actually ChipID,

Answer (score 0):

The die id should be unique : to identify a die, you need the lot number, the wafer number and the position on the wafer (maybe also the production line, if you don't have unique number for the wafers). This information allow to identify a die uniquely, and each chip has a different die id.

Nevertheless, I can't find any documentation on dieID for iOS. I can't guarantee that the dieID information is the full id of the die (so I can't guarantee uniqueness. I can only say "it should be").

Comment: Since the wafer number is laser scribed on the wafer (but not the die), the lot number is carried by the wafer "boat" or SMIF box and each die has a unique location on the wafer it is _possible_ that each die can be tracked.but each shot of the reticle in NOT unique, once the die comes out of wafer scribe unless they are tracked there is no way to know where the die or even lot that the die came from. This _can_ be electrically programmed into each die, this is a design decision not an inherent Fab capability. Unless you know specifically what is being done for this die you are just guessing.

Comment: @placeholder Ok, this means that we can not be sure if the die ID is unique, but it is likely that the ID is unique. Here is an example of the die ID "7372466802480". I think I have to build a little script that checks if the resulting hash is unique. I am hashing 6 "unique IDs" to one ID (but I am not sure if everyone of it is unique). Thanks for your help!

Comment: @DavidG.what I am saying is that the die by themselves inherently will be identical.  IF the designer added in programmability at wafer level then it is _possible_ perhaps even likely that there is a unique ID for each die.  For a high value die I'd say the possibility is higher.  For a low value die, very unlikely as that would add too much cost.  The Answer above implies that ALL die are unique and therefore it's likely. In fact all dies are indistinguishable _UNLESS_ they are programmed in NVRAM some way.

Comment: Identifying die is a common practice[1] to identify faulty production lots from in field failures, and on die eFuses are cheap. As Apple designs both hardware and software, it would be strange to provide an API to get a die ID if Apple can't get it on its products.

[1]: As datasheets are under NDA, I can't source this assertion.

Comment: each foundry, process, chip can have different solutions or no solution first off dont assume that all chips have an id.  dont assume they all have unique ids.  Some may be visual, some may be fused (at some point during the process on wafer, after being diced and packaged,...) think of little fuses that can be read and made available that are used for many things, one of which could be a collection of them that uniquely identify the chip.  thermal calibration, mac addresses, pll calibration, etc may or may not be fused as well.

Comment: depends heavily on the foundry, process initially and then the chip designers and what if any such features they want to add.  and/or the foundry might want to add for their own statistics (row and column of where the die was on the wafer).   things like year, run number and the x and y coordinate on the wafer would be the kind of thing you might see.  how those bits are decoded are probably not exposed to us or even folks under NDA, may be limited to employees.  to us its just a few dozen bits that we think are unique.